# $4\cos x^2 - 4\cos x = 2$, find all solutions in the interval $0^º\leq x\leq 360^º$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> $4\cos x^2 - 4\cos x = 2$, find all solutions in the interval $0^º\leq x\leq 360^º$

I'm not sure what I'm overlooking or not doing right but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried factoring out the $4\cos x$, tried factoring it from standard form...what am I missing?

Thank you for your time and I apologize for being dumb

Comment: Let $y=\cos(x)$ and use the quadratic formula after dividing by $2$.

Comment: @GitGud No, it's $\cos(x^2)$ not $\cos^2(x)$ according to what it says.

Comment: You apologize for not knowing how to do this problem. Lament not for learning is all about not knowing and then having to ask questions. I say: "He who asks is a fool for five minutes, but he who does not ask remains a fool forever." - Chinese proverb

Comment: @Shahar I commented before formatting. You're right.

Comment: So it's not $cos^2(x)$?  That makes this a totally different problem.  You would have to combine the two cosines into a single trig function which I'm not sure is even possible.  You may have to solve numerically if that's the equation.

Comment: This page shows formulas http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/sumProductCosSin.htm but I don't think they are going to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a quadratic so you have to solve the quadratic:

$$
4cos^2(x) - 4cos(x) = 2 \text{, substitute } X = cos(x) \\
4X^2 - 4X - 2 = 0
$$

Try to factor, multiply "first" and "last", then find factors which subtract to give the middle term:

$$
4\cdot-2 = -8 \\
8 = 2\cdot4, 4 - 2 = 2 \text{, nope} \\
8 = 1\cdot8, 8 - 1 = 7 \text{, nope}
$$

Those are all of the factors, so we cannot factor this.  Use the quadratic equation:

$$
X = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{4^2 - 4\cdot4\cdot-2}}{2\cdot4} \\
X = \frac{4\pm \sqrt{16 + 32}}{8} = \frac{4 \pm\sqrt{48}}{8} \\
X = \frac{4 \pm 4\sqrt{3}}{8} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

You can't solve this analytically, all you can do is say:

$$
cos(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

We can discard $\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}$ because that is greater than 1 (since $\sqrt{3} > 1$, $1 + \sqrt{3} > 2$).  This single solution is a negative value which means the two solutions are in the $2^\text{nd}$ and $3^\text{rd}$ quadrants.  You can take the inverse cosine (or arc-cosine) to find a numerical value, then you can use the unit circle to find the other solution:

$$
x = acos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \approx 111.47^\circ
$$

Indeed this is in the $2^\text{nd}$ quadrant.  Now to find the value in the 3rd quadrant, you can subtract this value from $360^\circ$.  I would actually visualize it by subtracting from $180^\circ$ (this gives the "principle" angle), then add that angle to $180^\circ$, if you do that you get $180^\circ - \theta + 180^\circ = 360^\circ - \theta$.  So the other angle is:

$$
\theta_2 \approx 360^\circ - 111.47^\circ = 248.53^\circ
$$

The only two solutions in your range therefore are:

$$
x \approx 111.47^\circ \text{ or } x \approx 248.53^\circ
$$

Comment: I really appreciate your time in explaining this! It helped out a ton

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a dumb question at all.

This equation is quadratic in $\cos x$, so you can solve it by factoring or by applying the quadratic formula. First, move everything to one side, and note that we can divide all terms by $2$:

$$4\cos^2 x - 4\cos x - 2=0$$
$$2\cos^2 x - 2\cos x - 1=0$$

We can give $\cos x$ a different name - call it $z$ - and then this is the same as:

$$2z^2 - 2z -1 = 0$$

...which you'll note is not factorable. Applying the quadratic formula, we obtain:

$$z=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4+8}}{4} = \frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

Since $z=\cos x$, we can say that there are two possibilities. Either $\cos x=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2$, or else $\cos x=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2$. The first option is not possible, because $\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2>1$. In the second case, though you can take the inverse cosine to get a value for $x$ that's a second quadrant angle. Then you'll have to use the unit circle to see which other angle has the same cosine.

Does that help?

Comment: It is factorable, just not in an easy-to-see way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said it's not factorable over $\Bbb{Q}$. I didn't want to bug the OP with that distinction. :/

Comment: Technically all polynomials are factorable.  I've always assumed that when one says a polynomial cannot be factored, it is assumed they mean with rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean $\cos^2 x$. It's quadratic formula for $\cos x$. Solve for it. You get some solutions. Be careful, you have to also invert $\cos x$ to finally get $x$ and at that point, you get more than two solutions per period (except for isolated special cases).

Answer (score 0):

If you make $y = \cos x$, the equation becomes $ 4 y^2 - 4y - 2 = 0$ which implies $ y = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt3}{2}$. Since $1 + \sqrt 3 > 2$ the only one you have to worry about is $y = \frac{1 - \sqrt 3}{2}$, that is, $\cos x = \frac{1 - \sqrt 3}{2}$. This is not solvable "by hand", so I believe the author of the question made some mistake or you're supposed to use a calculator to solve it. If you meant $y = \cos (x^2)$, then it's pretty much impossible algebraically.